# Prove that every absolutely summable series in L1 is summable

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through a real analysis book to study for my qualifying exams, and came across this problem. Let $\ell_1$ be the set of all real sequences such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert x_n \rvert < \infty$. Let $x_n^k$ be a sequence in $\ell_1$ Show that if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lVert x_n^k\rVert < \infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_n^k$ converges to some $x_n \in \ell_1$. I don't know where to start, and also don't use that $\ell_1$ is complete because the problem actually states to prove that $\ell_1$ is complete by showing that every absolutely summable series is summable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $N$ such that $ \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\|x_n^{k}\| <\epsilon$. Then show that $\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{N_2} |x_n^{k}| <\epsilon$ whenever $N_2>N_1>N$. Conclude that the partial sums of the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x_n^{k}$ form a Cauchy sequence so $x_n =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x_n^{k}$ exists. Now can you verify that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_n| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \|x_n^{k}\|$?

Comment: Thanks I think I got it. For the last part, is this correct? $\lVert x_n \rVert = \lVert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^k \rVert$. And so let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ then by repeated use of the triangle inequality, $\lVert \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n^k \rVert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N} \lVert x_n^k \rVert$, and since this holds for all N we have $\lVert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^k \rVert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lVert x_n^k \rVert$, and so $\lVert x_n \rVert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lVert x_n^k \rVert < \infty$ so $x_n \in \ell_1$?

Comment: @Aphyd Just put absolute value signs for $x_n^{k}$ and then you are in good shape.

Comment: Great thanks a lot

Comment: You might note that passing to the limit in your last step works because the norm is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Tonelli's theorem provides a shortcut:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lVert x_n^k\rVert = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|x_n^k|\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}|x_n^k|\right)<\infty$

which implies that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}|x_n^k|$ is an absolutely convergent series, hence $x_n:=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}x_n^k$ is a finite real number. Define $x=(x_n)$

Then, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_n^k|<\infty$ it follows that that $x\in \ell_1$.